# How to connect to S3 bucket with Git to push and fetch data

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-16.04, jgit

I have been trying to find a way to git to the AWS S3 bucket. While searching, I found this blog: https://fancybeans.com/2012/08/24/how-to-use-s3-as-a-private-git-repository/.

As per the blog says:

1. I have created S3 bucket (test-git-repo) and a folder inside (testing) and an IAM user with S3 bucket access
2. I have downloaded jgit-3.7.1 in my `/bin´ folder renamed as git.
3. created a `.git_s3_public` file and added both access keys saved in `/home/ubuntu` with `600` permission
4. in `/home/ubuntu/` I have created a directory `s3-git` and added some files with

   ```
   git init
   git add *
   git commit -m "my new files yay!"
   git remote add s3 amazon-s3://.jgit_s3_public@test-git-repo/tesing/s3-git
   jgit push s3 refs/heads/master
   ```

When I'm doing `jgit push` I'm getting the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set value to a final field 'org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Push.refSpecs'.
at org.kohsuke.args4j.spi.Setters.create(Setters.java:32)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:38)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.opt.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.opt.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.TextBuiltin.parseArguments(TextBuiltin.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.TextBuiltin.execute(TextBuiltin.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.execute(Main.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.run(Main.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

I have downloaded the .jar files for slf4j-jdk14.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-api.jar of version 1.7.5 and put them in /bin/ folder.

Still I'm getting the same error. I have tried a simple command

```
jgit config
```

still the same error

Can anybody help me out here to solve this issue or any other way to git to S3.

Comment: This looks like an issue specific to jgit rather than S3 and AWS.  I suggest you register on the jgit project forums and check whether this is a known issue.

Comment: I see you are new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly a solution to your problem but its a workaround. You may configure a git server into an EC2 for example and then use S3FS (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount the git servers data directory in S3. In that way, all your data will be stored in S3 without use jgit.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is not related to pushing to S3. The JGit command line utility fails while using reflection to apply the command line arguments to the JGit API.

This bug has been fixed with commit [a0558b709448cea01cc0725fff73408d9b223c72 - Remove final modifier on args4j option or argument fields](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=a0558b709448cea01cc0725fff73408d9b223c72)

Note that this bug only affects JGit's command line utility *pgm*. Pushing changes programmatically through the `PushCommand` API is not affected.

Use a recent version of JGit, e.g. 4.10 to overcome the problem.